# Elastic search nested if condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a case where condition1 and condition2 must match but condition4 must match if condition3 is true.

```
if(condition1&&Condition2) {
if(condition3) {
if(condition4) {
}

}
}
```

Condition1 and Condition2 can be easily achieved by using must but condition3 and condition4 is tricky because none of must and should seem to work.